# Find duplicated rows in MySQL with QueryDSL JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, querydsl

I would like to execute this SQL request in QueryDSL JPA

```
SELECT authorizationitem.* 
FROM authorizationitem 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT `authorize` 
    FROM authorizationitem 
    GROUP BY `authorize` 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) a2 
    ON authorizationitem.`authorize` = a2.`authorize`;
```

in order to find duplicated row in a table, i should execute this request. But with QueryDSL, i cannot find the way to write this.

It seems QueryDSL does not allow subQuery in Inner Join :s

Any suggestion?

Thanks
regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can't express this with HQL/JPQL, so you will need to expess this with SQL. Querydsl JPA provides the possibility to express both JPQL and SQL queries through its API.

Comment: Hi Timo, could you give me an example? I do not see how to do. Thanks

Comment: Here is the related part of the reference docs http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.8.0/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e343

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a subquery in the WHERE clause, but it will probably be less efficient than the subquery in the FROM clause.  Make sure there is an index on authorizationitem.authorize to optimize the joins and the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT authorizationitem.* 
FROM authorizationitem 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT `authorize` 
    FROM authorizationitem2 
   WHERE authorizationitem2.authorize = authorizationitem.authorize
    GROUP BY `authorize` 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
);
```

or

```
SELECT authorizationitem.* 
FROM authorizationitem 
WHERE (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM authorizationitem2 
   WHERE authorizationitem2.authorize = authorizationitem.authorize
    GROUP BY `authorize` 
) > 1;
```